# Chevalley Decomposition of $x+y$ in terms of Chevalley decomposition of $x$ and $y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Given $V$ finite dimensional vector space on an algebraically closed field $k$ write for $x\in \text{End}_k(V)$
>   \begin{gather}
> x=x_s+x_n
> \end{gather}
>   the Chevalley decomposition of $x$ with $x_s$ diagonalizable and $x_n$ nilpotent.
>   Let $x,y \in \text{End}_k(V)$ be such that $xy=yx$, then
>   \begin{gather}
> (x+y)_s=x_s+y_s \\ (x+y)_n=x_n+y_n
> \end{gather}

How can I prove it?
If I show that $x_sy_s=y_sx_s$ then $x_s$ and $y_s$ admit a simultaneous basis of eigenvectors, then $x_s+y_s$ is diagonalizable and $x+y-(x_s-y_s)=x_n+y_n$ is nilpotent since sum of nilpotent matrices, and we get the result.

Comment: Yes? You just proved it yourself. To conclude, you just need to use the uniqueness property of decomposing an endomorphism as a sum of a semisimple one and a nilpotent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $x_s$ and $y_s$ commute, you just need to observe that there exist polynomials $p(T)$ and $q(T)$ such that $p(x)=x_s$ and $q(y)=y_s$.

To do this consider the characteristic polynomial for $x$: $\chi_x(T)=\prod_i(T-a_i)^{m_i}$. Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem you can find a polynomial satisfying the congruences $p(T)\equiv a_i$ (mod $(T-a_i)^{m_i})$. This is the polynomial you are looking for.

A detailed proof can be found in Humphreys' Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory (pages 17-18).

Comment: I am reading the proof on Humphreys' book, it's very nice. 
Thank you to for the solution!